# Swiper loop bug

Tags: loops, swiper.js

Since I added this code to have a fraction counter, the loop does not work anymore.

```
<script>    const fraction = document.getElementById("fraction");
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".swiper-slide");
const slideCount = slides.length;
fraction.textContent = `1 / ${slideCount}`;

const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  // If we need pagination

  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination"
  },

  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
  },
            

  on: {
    slideChange: () => {
      fraction.textContent = `${swiper.realIndex + 1} / ${slideCount}`;
    }
  }
});</script>
```

Html code:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="empty-space col-xs-b55 col-sm-b110"></div>
            <div class="empty-space col-xs-b30 col-sm-b60"></div>   
            <div class="swiper-container" data-auto-height="0.0" data-autoplay="5000" data-loop="1" data-pagination=".swiper-pagination">
                
                <div id="fraction" class="swiper-fraction"></div>               
                 <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button hidden-xs style-3"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button hidden-xs style-3"></div>              
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                        <div class="portfolio-detail-entry">
                            <div class="homepage-2-6-slider">                               
                                   <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" alt="" data-src="1.jpg"  class="lazyload"/>                            
                                 <a class="entry full-size" href="#"> 
                                        <span class="text text-center">
                                        <span class="slide-description simple-article light transparent">lopsum  </span>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I updated to the latest version of swiper.js but it still doesn't work.
I added a loop: true directly in the counter js code but it doesn't work.
I don't know what to do anymore...